# DOM createElement() dynamically with click event to div specific url element

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to build a 9 divs (cards) dynamically containing information about store branch locations. Each card has a unique URL associated with it that links to each branches specific URL.

This approach, within the function, appends the first (0) URL to all the cards:

```
$("div").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    return false;
});
```

This approach appends the last URL (8) to all the cards:

```
branch.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(prop.pages_url);   
})
```

Code I'm working with:

```
function buildLocationList(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var currentFeature = data.features[i];
    var prop = currentFeature.properties;

    //Create Card
    var branches = document.getElementById('branches');
    var url = branches.appendChild(document.createElement('a');
        url.setAttribute('href', prop.pages_url);
    )
    var branch = branches.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        branch.className = 'card';
        branch.id = "branch-" + i;
        branch.url = prop.pages_url;

        branch.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.open(prop.pages_url);

          })  
    //Append Branch Card Details
    v
    var company = branch.appendChild(document.createElement('h5'));
      company.innerHTML = prop.name + '<br />';
    var distancePhone = branch.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        if (prop.distance) {
          var roundedDistance = Math.round(prop.distance * 100) / 100;
          distancePhone.innerHTML = '<span class="miles">Approx. ' + roundedDistance + ' miles</span>' + '<span class="location-phone">' + prop.phone_number + '</span>';
        }
        else {
          distancePhone.innerHTML = prop.phone_number;
        }
    var address = branch.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        if (prop.address_line_2) {
          address.innerHTML += prop.address_line_1 + ', ' + prop.address_line_2 + '<br />';
        }
        else {
          address.innerHTML += prop.address_line_1 + '<br />';
        };
        address.innerHTML += prop.address_city + ', ' + prop.address_state + ' ' +prop.address_postal_code  + '</p>';
  }
}
```

I would like the card to be clickable with a redirect to each branch's unique URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the URL on the card element:

```
branch.url = prop.pages_url
```

All you need to do in the click handler is access the property:

```
branch.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(e.currentTarget.url);
})
```

In the context of the event handler, `e.currentTarget` is the element to which the handler is attached. If you were interested in which element fired the event, you'd use `e.target`.

Here's your code snippet modified below. I don't think the links will open on here though due to the sandboxed iframe.

```js
function buildLocationList(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
    var currentFeature = data.features[i];
    var prop = currentFeature.properties;

    //Create Card
    var branches = document.getElementById('branches');
    var url = branches.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
        url.setAttribute('href', prop.pages_url);
    var branch = branches.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        branch.className = 'card';
        branch.id = "branch-" + i;
        branch.url = prop.pages_url;

        branch.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e.currentTarget.url);
            window.open(e.currentTarget.url);
        })  
    //Append Branch Card Details
    var company = branch.appendChild(document.createElement('h5'));
        company.innerHTML = prop.name + '<br />';
    var distancePhone = branch.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        if (prop.distance) {
          var roundedDistance = Math.round(prop.distance * 100) / 100;
          distancePhone.innerHTML = '<span class="miles">Approx. ' + roundedDistance + ' miles</span>' + '<span class="location-phone">' + prop.phone_number + '</span>';
        }
        else {
          distancePhone.innerHTML = prop.phone_number;
        }
    var address = branch.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        if (prop.address_line_2) {
          address.innerHTML += prop.address_line_1 + ', ' + prop.address_line_2 + '<br />';
        }
        else {
          address.innerHTML += prop.address_line_1 + '<br />';
        };
        address.innerHTML += prop.address_city + ', ' + prop.address_state + ' ' +prop.address_postal_code  + '</p>';
  }
}

buildLocationList({features:[{
  properties: {
    distance: 100,
    name: 'Google',
    pages_url: 'https://www.google.com',
    phone_number: '123-456-7890',
    address_line_1: '1234 Street',
    address_city: 'Citytown',
    address_state: 'State',
    address_postal_code: '12345'
  }
},{
  properties: {
    distance: 200,
    name: 'Microsoft',
    pages_url: 'https://www.microsoft.com',
    phone_number: '123-456-7890',
    address_line_1: '1234 Street',
    address_city: 'Citytown',
    address_state: 'State',
    address_postal_code: '12345'
  }
}]})
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="branches"></div>
```

Comment: Worked perfect!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="//jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery">w3schools</a>
        </div>

<script>
   $("div").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("a").data("value");            
    });
</script>
```